# need for an example of synchronous but non periodic interrupt

Tags: os-kernel

I know that synchronous interrupts are interrupts that occur with a clock tick (after finishing an instruction) and I think that periodic if they happen in every n ticks of the clock. To get a better grasp of understanding periodic interrupts I tried without success to find a synchronous but non periodic interrupt.
would appreciate your help :)

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/ch04.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that if a process makes itself sleep then the interrupt when the alarm will wake him up will be such an interrupt.